# How do I retrieve data from jsp pageContext

Tags: java, jsp

The following line of java code is giving me null `pageContext.getRequest().getParameter("id");`

When I print it out in jsp page using `<%=request.getAttribute("id")%>` I am able to see the data stored inside.

Is there another way to retrieve the data from the jsp page and assign it to a java variable?

Comment: give us an example and give us what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Request parameter != request attribute

Comment: @LluisMartinez how would I set the data into the pageContext parameter in jsp? As getRequest() doesnt have setParameter();

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. Place your code between <% %>

```
<%
String userID = request.getParameter("userid");
out.println(userID);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid scriptlets you can use JSTL:

```
<c:set var="userId" value="${param.usedId}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSP you can use internal java function

if do you want to pull a query parameter you simply have to write

```
<%request.getParameter("id") %>
```

if do you want to assign something like you want to put a data inside P tag you simply have to write

```
<p><%=request.getParameter("message")%></p>
```

in this case your java message will be inside P tag

and like javascript variable

```
<script>var id=<%=request.getParameter("id")%></script>
```

here you have assigned id (javascript variable) with query parameter pulled from native java function, id do you want to assign normal java variable inside jsp you have simply write

```
<% String message=request.getParameter("message")%>
```

Hope this help :)